# Getting "cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory" With standalone Toolchain

Tags: android-ndk

I am using a standalone tool chain and I am trying to cross compile FreeType2. When I run...

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --without-zlib --prefix=/tmp/freetype
```

It fails with the following...

```
configure:2954: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/tmp/my-toolchain/sysroot -V >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2965: $? = 1
configure:2954: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/tmp/my-toolchain/sysroot -qversion >&5
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized option '-qversion'
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2965: $? = 1
configure:2985: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3007: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/tmp/my-toolchain/sysroot -std=gnu99       conftest.c  >&5
/private/tmp/my-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
```

From everything I read this was a sysroot issue but as you can see I added sysroot AND I am using a Standalone toolchain.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Are you using make-standalone-toolchain.sh?

Comment: "I am using a Standalone toolchain." So I made the toolchain then exported CC ar etc

Comment: I would check config.log more carefully to see the problem.

Comment: Are you refering to the unreconizeable options? I saw that but I don't know how to fix it. That is why I posted the log in the first place

Comment: @Jackie Initially, with a standalone build, sysroot is optional so, it's strange that you get the not found error. Are you sure `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` is actually pointing to your standalone build and not to a prebuilt one?